# Can not clean project in android studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Today I have updated Android Studio to 3.2 and my whole project is corrupt. I have again start with old backup but it can not clean or even run project which was works fine before in old android studio. Below is screenshot of error.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try "Invalidate caches / restart" from file menu

Comment: Try everything nothing works.

Comment: There are so many reason for this. This same problem i faced just before week and i have do search and got the solution after 2 days. So just add in question's that what you have tried ?

Comment: there was bug in androidannotations version 4.4.0 with android studio 3.2 but in new version of annotation(4.5.0) everything fixed and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was bug in androidannotations version 4.4.0 with android studio 3.2 but in new version of annotation(4.5.0) everything fixed and it works fine.